# Regex for Key-value pairs

Tags: regex

I need a regex for parsing key-value-pairs for equations like :

```
c=a+b
```

I think that it has to match the following case:

```
Key = value value value
```

I used the following:

```
(\b\w+).?=(.*?(?=\s\w+=|$))
```

but it is not working. Any suggestions.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: is the value always like `a+b` and not `x=a+b-c%d*e`?

Comment: It can take that format too. I just need to know how to express multiple values.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/eX3hP7/1
is this good?

Comment: Not exactly. The regex is not matching c=a+b. Thanks anyway.

Comment: its matching https://regex101.com/r/eX3hP7/2
do you want `a`, `b` in different variable

Comment: It is matching. Thanks. Do you know any good resources to master regex?

Comment: I suggest you to read `Mastering Regular Expression`. This is one of the best book that I read so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex

```
(\w+)\s*=((?:\w+[-+*%])*?\w+)$
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/eX3hP7/3)**

Modified version with spaces

```
(\w+)\s*=((?:\s*\w+\s*[-+\/*%])*?\s*\w+\s*)$
```

Comment: Can I have a regex that treats a,b and the operator in different variables.Thanks

Comment: @Deant you can do it but you require a programming language to access these values..regex alone won't do it

Comment: Keep in mind that this doesn't support `/`, spaces anywhere except before the `=` or parenthesis. Example: `c = (a + b) / d`. Just curious: why is it that you need a regex for this?

Comment: @Andrew handling parenthesis will be a lot more difficult task using regex

Comment: @rock321987 Any ideas on how I can access these values in javascript

Comment: @Deant whatever regex you put in `()` are known as capturing group..their result is stored in a variable.. In JS you can access these values as `$1`, `$2` etc..
https://regex101.com/r/jX6cZ6/1 see on the right side, you will find all the matched expression..`$1` contains `a`, `$2` contains `b` etc.

Comment: @Deant I suggest you to read regular expressions first. You will get everything

Comment: @rock321987 Thanks for your help. Greatly appreciated.